# Recursion for church numerals in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I have defined Church numeral zero and some other standard functions on church numerals according to Wikipedia definitions as following:

```
(define n0 (λ (f x) x))

(define newtrue
  (λ(m n) m))

(define newfalse
  (λ(m n) n))

(define iszero
  (λ(m) (m (λ(x) newfalse) newtrue)))

(define ifthenelse
  (λ(a b c) (a b c)))
```

Using these, I write a recursion loop as:

```
(((λ(r) (λ(n) (ifthenelse (iszero n) n ((r r) n))))
   (λ(r) (λ(n) (ifthenelse (iszero n) n ((r r) n))))) n0)
```

Now for argument `n0` as above, this should return `n0`, without going into recursion. But it doesn't. Why?

Note 1: This recursion loop works perfectly fine with ordinary numerals and ordinary functions:

```
(((λ(r) (λ(n) (if (= 0 n) n ((r r) n))))
   (λ(r) (λ(n) (if (= 0 n) n ((r r) n))))) 0)
```

This returns `0` as it should.

Note 2: Functions `ifthenelse`, `iszero`, `newtrue`, `newfalse` also work fine on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the loop is that the semantics of functions in Scheme is to always evaluate all its arguments.

In your second example:

```
(((λ(r) (λ(n) (if (= 0 n) n ((r r) n))))
   (λ(r) (λ(n) (if (= 0 n) n ((r r) n))))) 0)
```

you are using `if`, which is a special form that does *not* evaluate the third argument if the condition is true. So, it evaluates `(= 0 n)` and returns immediately `0`, since the condition is `#true`, without evaluating the third argument `((r r) n)`.

Instead, in the first example:

```
(((λ(r) (λ(n) (ifthenelse (iszero n) n ((r r) n))))
   (λ(r) (λ(n) (ifthenelse (iszero n) n ((r r) n))))) n0)
```

`ifthenelse` is a function, so that, according to the evaluation rules of Scheme, *all* its arguments are evaluated, including `((r r) n)`, and this causes an endless loop.

Comment: Can you suggest how to make my `ifthenelse` work like usual `if`?

Comment: The evaluation rules of Lisp languages are not totally equivalent to the Beta reduction rules of lambda calculus, so that what you are trying to do is not possible, for what I know.

Comment: Hooray! Was able to do it using the lazy evaluation feature of scheme.

Comment: Excellent! Post as an answer to your own question.